# How to get children of a type in Cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

What is the correct way to get an array of children that have a certain name with the new Cocos2D v3 ?

`getChildByTag` is no longer supported, and `getChildByName` returns only one node.

Comment: getChildByTag also returns only one node (the first one found with the tag). Then you would have to walk the children array if you wanted multiple children with the tag.

Comment: Hello the question is refering to Version 3 of Cocos2d-iphone. Tags are no longer supported. I could manually recursevly loop all the children and check, sure. The getting of children seemed to be extensively used in v2.1 and was quite useful, that is why I thought that there is a similar mechanism in v3. Apparently this way is no longer prefered, using the UIResponder methods seems to be privileged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation of Cocos2d v3.4](http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/docs/api/Classes/CCNode.html#//api/name/children) you can get all children from the CCNode class by self.children and traverse them in a FOR-EACH LOOP to match the name property and get the desired children.

```
for (CCNode* child in self.children)
{
    if ([child.name isEqualToString:@"theSprite"])
    {      
        // do stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was not available when I have asked the question. It might help some people out though.